# Is there any way to install an app which need .net 3.5 without .net 3.5?

Tags: installation, .net-framework

I want to install vmware viclient 5.5, it need .net framework 3.5 for running.
But I cannot install .net 3.5, because I used Windows Thin PC, if I want to get 3.5, I have to customize and reinstall it.(seems)

However, I can and already installed .net 4.5, but the viclient installer still prompt need .net 3.5.

I heard .net app can redirect runtime from old version to new version in a config file, but it need the app has been installed at first.

So, Is there any method can let me use viclient under Windows Thin PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I resolved it:

1. Install viclient on another computer
2. Install .net 4.0 on Thin PC.
3. Copy installed viclient to Thin PC and run it.

It works fine.